# How to retrieve audio channels, bit rate and other quality measurements for a given track ID

Tags: shell-script, audio, multimedia

I have this code :

```
track1=$(mkvmerge -I sample.mkv | sed -ne '/^Track ID [0-9]*: audio ([^)]*).* language:eng.*/ { s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/;H }; $ { g;s/[^0-9]/,/g;s/^,//;p }' | cut -c1)
```

It will retrieve the 1 track matching language english.

I want to make a script to compare between same language audio tracks, and find the one with the highest quality.

But `mkvinfo`, `mkvmerge` and `mediainfo` doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the information about a given track ID, and I don't know how to parse their full output to retrieve only what I need.

How to do this? I need to retrieve everything that could be needed to guess quality, like format, bit rate, number of channels, size and store it in a variable like `track1channels`.

I'm open to other solutions that solve this difficult issue.

Comment: You can get that info using `ffprobe`. For example: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries streams /path/to/file`

Comment: It doesn't seem easier to parse ffprobe :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably many different ways to do it, depending on what tool you want to use to parse the output. One way is to make `mkvmerge` produce JSON, and then parse it with `jq`. For example, to get all audio tracks:

```
mkvmerge --identify --identification-format json sample.mkv | jq '.tracks[] | select(.type=="audio")'
```

You can specifiy all sorts of criteria in `jq`, for example `.id=="2"` for track 2 etc. Maybe you can even do the comparison/sorting with `jq`, depending on what you want to do, see `man jq` for details.

You can also store some filtered output from `jq` in a shell variable, and the use multiple `jq` calls to extract all the fields into other shell variables. (Possibly there's a way to do that in parallel, but I don't know it).

**Edit**

As for the bitrate: I tried with a sample `mkv` which contains `AAC` audio, but neither `mediainfo` nor `mkvinfo` give any bitrate purely for audio in the first place. Possibly one could calculate it from other information, like total bits used for this track and total duration, but I am not familiar enough with the internals of a mkv container to pinpoint which number is which.

The `.tracks[] | select(.type=="audio")` reads "stream all information in the `track` field, and then select those which have an `type` field which equals `audio`". Say you get something like

```
{
  "codec": "AAC",
  "id": 1,
  "properties": {
    "audio_channels": 2,
    "audio_sampling_frequency": 44100,
    "codec_id": "A_AAC",
    "codec_private_data": "1210",
    "codec_private_length": 2,
    "default_duration": 23219954,
    "default_track": true,
    "enabled_track": true,
    "forced_track": true,
    "language": "und",
    "minimum_timestamp": 0,
    "number": 2,
    "uid": 2897612726
  },
  "type": "audio"
}
```

then save it into a file or variable. Pipe this into a second `jq` command like `jq '.properties.audio_channels'` to get subfields. I am not sure how you intend to loop over multiple tracks or what you want to do, but you can do a lot just with `jq` queries alone.

**Edit**

To get id, codec name, codec id, and number of channels on a single line, do something like

```
jq '[[.id, .codec, .properties.codec_id, .properties.audio_channels] | map(tostring) | join(",")] | join("\n")'
```

on the saved value (or add to the original expression).

The outer `[...]` captures the stream of JSON records, the inner `[...]` constructs a list which can be `join`ed with a comma after converting numbers to strings, and then the outer list is also `join`ed by newlines. I guess one could get rid of the quotes with commandline options, if necessary.

Also look into `sort` if you want to sort by number of channels first, etc.

This is really turning into a "how do I use `jq` properly" question, so maybe google a `jq` tutorial, or make a new question/new questions?

Comment: Just look at some JSON example, e.g. the above output. It's really obvious.